# Would it be wise to prepay for 10 years on domain registration?

Tags: domains

I have a domain name coming up to expire soon and i use it for business. Would it be wise to just pay for 10 years assuming prices are going to go up? I can't forsee it going down.

Comment: If you are offered a compelling price why not? Just make sure it is a reputable high quality registrar first. No sense locking into what ends up being a lousy deal because the company is no good. Of course you can still transfer if you need to. But who knows who will honor what deal when you do. Choose wisely and it can be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to register domains for 5 or 10 years at a time for several reasons:

- You can get a better price.   When you register for multiple years you are often offered a discount.
- I don't have to worry about renewing the domain every year.  Taking the yearly hassle off my plate is worth something to me.
- Long registration periods may be seen as a sign of commitment and quality to Google for ranking purposes.   You certainly don't have a "throwaway" domain name then.

Of course, I don't register a domain name for that long when I'm unsure if I 'm going to really use it.